# ReduxForm - onSubmit method is not called for submit() function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a problem with `onSubmit` method when it is called from `onChange` event.

If a form below is submitted by a submit button function `buttonOnSubmit` is called.

But if the form is submitted by function `props.submit()` in `onChange` event, the function `buttonOnSubmit` is not called.

Do you have idea why? I was trying to find explanation in documentation and also on the internet but I failed.

Thank you.

```
  const Form = props => {
    // this method is called if submit button is clicked, it is not called from onChange event
    const buttonOnSubmit = (formData) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (props.onSubmit) {
          props.onSubmit(formData);
        }
      });
    };

    return (
      <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit(buttonOnSubmit)}>
        ....
      </form>
    );
  };

  return reduxForm({
    form: 'name',
    onChange: (values, dispatch, props) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          props.submit();
        }, 0);
    }
  })(Form);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi Wanna help but do you have more codes to share ? This is not complete your code i guess.
reduxForm({
    form: 'name',
    onChange: (values, dispatch, props) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          props.submit();
        }, 0);
    }
  })(Form);
What is your reduxForm ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This should be a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: I couldn't add my comment because of 50 reputations score policy. Sorry

Comment: reduxForm is function from redux-form library.